# How to align left my radio buttons and checkboxes like I can do it easily with paragraphs?

Tags: html, css

And I used margin-right:-9rem; in input element. But it didn't sound its good approach to me, idk why. But is there a better option how do do it? I was just trying my radio button and checkboxes near the boxes.
I have been trying to do survey form to practice my html and css knowledge. Please help me.

```css
body {
    background-color: rgb(25, 230, 161);
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}
h1 {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    margin-top: 2rem;
}
#description, #welcome {
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
}
main {
    width: 60%;
    border: 2px solid red;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 1rem 2rem; /*margin moves the border, padding changes the inside elements, not position of border.*/

}

label {
    display: block; /*make labels one under the other */
    padding-bottom: .3rem;
    padding-top: 1rem;
}
input {
    width:20rem;
    margin-right: -9rem;
}
[for="dropdown"] {
    margin-top: 1rem;
}
p {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <h1 id="title">LearningHtmlCss Course Survey Form</h1>
    <p id="description">This survey page is built for gathering information about people taking this course. So that we can improve our site.</p>
    <p id="welcome">Thank you for taking time to help us improve the platform</p>

    <main>
        <form id="survey-form">
            <label for="name" id="name-label">Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name" required>
    
            <label for="email" id="email-label">Email</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="username@gmail.com" pattern=".+@gmail.com" title="Please provide only gmail address" placeholder="Enter your email" required> <!--email validation-->
    
            <label for="age" id="number-label">Age</label>
            <input type="number" id="age" min="7" max="99" placeholder="between 7, and 99"  required>
    
            <label for="dropdown">Which option best describes your current role?</label>
            <select name="current role" id="dropdown">
                
                <option>Select current role</option>
                <option value="student">Student</option>
                <option value="job">Full time job</option>
                <option value="learner">Full time learner</option>
                <option value="not to say">Prefer not to say</option>
                <option value="other">Other</option>
    
            </select>
    
            <p>Would you recommend LearningHtmlCss course to a friend?</p>
    
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="option" value="Definitely" checked>Definitely
            </label>
    
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="option" value="Maybe">Maybe
            </label>
    
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="option" value="Not sure">Not sure
            </label>
    
    
            <p>What would you like to see improved?</p>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="front-end" value="front-end">Front-end projects
            </label>

            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="back-end" value="back-end">Back-end projects
            </label>
            
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="forum" value="forum">Forum
            </label>

            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="videos" value="videos">Videos
            </label>

            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="city-meetups" value="city-meetups">City Meetups
            </label>

            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="additional" value="additional">Additional courses
            </label>
    
                   
            
    
            <label for="comments">Any comments or suggestions?</label>
            <input type="textarea" name="comment" id="comments" placeholder="Enter your comment here...">
    
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>    
    
        </form>
        

    </main>
    
</body>
```

Comment: like that? - https://ibb.co/h28Cgvt

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov yes, exactly. That's what I wanted. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to correct the position of the radio and the checkbox of the buttons, you need to replace the css rules of this `input`:

```
input {
    width: 20rem;
    margin-right: -9rem;
}
```

Replace with this one:

```
input {
    width: auto;
    margin: 0 5px 0 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Mr. I appreciate it a lot.

Comment: Always glad to help

Comment: But can you please tell me what that "auto" means there? When i change it from auto to something else, the positions of button and checkboxes change too. Width is only about its size, isn't it? I just didnt understand what is "width" to do with aligning it left?

Comment: @Semih, because your inputs are inside the label tag - https://ibb.co/DRwV2MK

Comment: @Semih, Since these css rules relate to input, then when the width changes, this will happen - https://ibb.co/bQygkSX

Comment: sir, thanks so much. Now I understand it clearly.